# Why I get Error "No such file or directory", when I try to include a header file?

Tags: c++

I have `main.cpp` and `add.cpp` `add.h` files

When I try to include `add.h` I get following compilation error

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: add.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <add.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here is the code:

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <add.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`add.cpp`

```
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
};
```

`add.h`

```
int add(int x, int y);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#include <add.h>` causes the compiler to search the system include directories for the file `add.h`, but not the current directory.  If you want to include a file `add.h` which is in the current directory, use:

```cpp
#include "add.h"
```

Comment: As an addendum, if a header file included using quotes can't be found in the same directory as the source file, then the compiler will look in the usual list of directories.

Comment: One could also use the compiler option `-I` (upper-case i) to add a specific directory to the list the compiler uses to search for header files. But using quotes as shown in this answer is the normal way to include local header files.